# GStreamer 0.1 | gst_pad_renegotiate is missing?

Tags: c, gstreamer

I working on custom `GStreamer` plugin based on 'GstPushSrc'.

In some cases I need to start reconfiguration because, I changing `GstCaps` on src pad.

To do this, I have plan to use `gst_pad_renegotiate` but I can't find it in `GStreamer 0.1` branch (`git://anongit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer`)

Can someone explain what is the right way to notify all downstream `GstElement`'s about `GstCaps` has been changed?

**Update**

The similar problem for another functions that I can find in documentation but cannot find in GStreamer 0.1 sources. Examples

1. `gst_pad_try_set_caps`
2. `gst_pad_use_explicit_caps`

Comment: I truly hope you are not working with gstreamer 0.1 ... we are at version 1.4 (stable) for the moment

Comment: There are two recommended branches: 1.0 and 1.4. I would recommend trying to work at the latest stable branch.

Comment: Could you please confirm that I can use GStreamer 1.0 for iOS/Android also?

Comment: I haven't got a clue about that, but gstreamer 0.1 dates from 2001... I guess that might be slightly outdated

Comment: @ChrisMaes Thanks for advice, then moving to 1.0 helps me to solve my problem. If you have will decided to write an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

There are two recommended branches: 1.0 and 1.4. I would recommend trying to work at the latest stable branch. – Chris Maes